# How to display both single and double quotes in textbox or textarea

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, html-entities, html-encode

In the database, the data string has both single and double quotes in them.

Data string.

`A'B"C`

When it's displayed in a `textbox` or `textarea`, it's automatically encoded to html entities.

Code in MVC view, `vm` is the object binded with knockout.

`vm.field1('@Model.field1');`

Rendered HTML.

`A&#39;B&quot;C`

How do I make both of them display as single and double quotes again?

I tried to encode double quotes to `&quot;`:

`vm.field1("Html.Raw(Model.field1.Replace("\"", "&quot;"))");`

But that gave me:

`A'B&quot;C`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to escape double or single quotes.

escape single quotes:

`vm.field1('@Html.Raw(Model.field1.Replace("'", "\\\'"))');`

or escape double quotes:

`vm.field1("@Html.Raw(Model.field1.Replace("\"", "\\\""))")`

**Update**

I found that there is security problem with my original solution. 
If the input is `A'B'C</SCRIPT>`, it'll break the javascript on the page. 
To resolve that, I HTML encode everything except single and double quotes.

```
vm.field1('Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.field1).Replace("&#39", "\\\'").Replace("&quot;", "\""))');
```

**Update 2**

I found the AntiXss library has some tools for this and I found this will be even better.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ToQuotedJsString(this string s)
    {
        return Micorosoft.Security.Application.Encoder.JavaScriptEncode(s, true);
    }
}
```

then in the View:

```
vm.field1(@Html.Raw(Model.field1.ToQuotedJsString()));
```

Comment: In first "Update" change the "&quote;" to "&quot;"